# Web scraping application doesn't work anymore when moved onto docker container

Tags: c#, html, docker

```
public static HtmlNode GetHtml(string link)
        {

            _scrapingBrowser.IgnoreCookies = true;
            _scrapingBrowser.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
            _scrapingBrowser.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 6.0)" +
                " (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
            _scrapingBrowser.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            WebPage _webPage = _scrapingBrowser.NavigateToPage(new Uri(link));            
            return _webPage.Html;

        }
```

This is the code I'm using to grab the data off the web page, it works fine when I run it on my desktop but when I run it in a docker container it stops working. I think it has to do with the encoding but I'm not sure.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY NuGet.Config ./ 
COPY ["OnlineFindsBot.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./OnlineFindsBot.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "OnlineFindsBot.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "OnlineFindsBot.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY config.json ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OnlineFindsBot.dll"]
```

Here is my Dockerfile I am using.

The html.Content isn't at all readable when it is in the docker container, just a bunch of characters

Comment: Try to run the docker image with network mode `host`

Comment: Yeah I tried that still no luck